# Drill Indicators VBA Pivot Table

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, drilldown

I am currently using VBA in excel 2010 and have created a pivot table that I would like to format based on certain things. I am trying to get the +/- buttons removed from the table using

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HoldersPivotTable").ShowDrillIndicators = False
```

but that isn't working for some reason.

Help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub PivotTable_Creation_And_Formatting()

    'PURPOSE: Creates a brand new Pivot table on a new worksheet from data in the ActiveSheet

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim StartPvt As String
    Dim SrcData As String
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Determine the data range you want to pivot
    SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "E")).Address

    'Create a new worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("HOLDERS (CORP)")

    'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?

    StartPvt = sht.Range("A1").Address

    'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
    Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

    'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=sht.Range(StartPvt), _
    TableName:="HoldersPivotTable")

    pvt.PivotFields("SECURITY SHORT DESCRIPTION").Orientation = xlRowField

    'Add item to the Row Labels
    pvt.PivotFields("HOLDERS").Orientation = xlRowField

    'Add item to the Row Labels
    pvt.PivotFields("POSITION").Orientation = xlRowField

    'Add item to the Row Labels
    pvt.PivotFields("LATEST CHANGE").Orientation = xlRowField

    'Add item to the Row Labels
    pvt.PivotFields("FILE DT").Orientation = xlRowField

    pvt.ColumnGrand = False
    pvt.RowGrand = False

    'Show in Tabular Form
    pvt.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

    For Each pf In pvt.PivotFields
        pf.Subtotals(1) = True
        pf.Subtotals(1) = False
    Next pf

    Sheets("HOLDERS (CORP)").Select
    Columns("A:E").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 13.43
    Columns("A:E").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

    Columns("B:E").Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 226)
    Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 226)

    With Range("A1:E1").Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HoldersPivotTable").ShowDrillIndicators = False

    Range("B1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work if you do it manually or record a macro? The `+/-` buttons are disabled when no pivot table is selected, so you might have to select it or try it after the `.CreatePivotTable` line

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to read:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HoldersPivotTable").ShowDrillIndicators = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HoldersPivotTable").PivotCache.Refresh
```

This will re-display the pivot without the drilldown indicators.  You have to refresh the pivot to get the changes to appear.

If it still does not work, then check for a

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

that doesn't have the corresponding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HoldersPivotTable").ShowDrillIndicators = False` Should it be ``ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HoldersPivotTable").EnableDrilldown = False` Iam not sure but just give it a try.